# Extract occurrences of character in file line by line

Tags: bash

I have a large file of a bilingual lexicon with lines formatted as:

```
abatement: disminucion; mitigacion; moderacion; rebaja; deduccion; supresion; anulacion
```

I'm trying to find out which line has the most translated words, and so am looking to find the line with the most occurrences of `;`, and then echo the English word.

I've managed to get something close but it uses sed to trim off data, meaning I can't match the English word back to the line.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you still need to do it in `bash`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -F'[:;]' '{if(NF>n){n=NF;w=$1}}END{print w}' filename
```

Comment: This is great, could you explain it a little for me?

Comment: Nice answer but move the condition into the condition part of the awk body: `awk -F'[:;]' 'NF>n{n=NF;w=$1}END{print w}' filename`

Answer (score 1):

Treating `;` as a field separator, the line with the `;` will have the most fields.

```
while IFS=';' read -a fields; do
    n=${#fields[@]}
    if (( n > max )); then
       max=$n
       english=${fields[0]%:}
    fi
done < file.txt
echo "$english"
```